# Eventually or ultimately?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I would like to know what word would fit best in the following sentence about computing:

> As the database size increased, the memory used by the program grew up which ultimately lead to a crash.

I am hesitating between "ultimately" and "eventually", but if anyone has a better idea, please share it with the community!

The information that I want to convey is:

- The crash has happened.
- It is an abrupt consequence of the memory growth. Before the crash, everything was working fine, which explains why nobody saw the problem coming.
- However, the crash was still previsible: it was sure that one day the database size would be such that it will make the program use all the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, at least to me, "ultimately" may imply that the crash was a second-order effect of the memory usage (that is, the memory usage caused something else which in turn, possibly after a chain of events, caused the crash), whereas "eventually" implies that the crash is a first-order effect of the growth of memory usage and the passing of time.

That's a rather fine point, and, frankly, I doubt anybody would notice the distinction -- your ultimate intent will likely be clear from the context.

More importantly: "Grew up" in this context is not correct, either as idiom or in a formal setting.

A little boy "grows up", eventually becoming a grown-up -- implicit is that not only did the boy grow larger, but he also matured, in the sense of ceasing being childish.  Computer memory wouldn't be expected to do that.

[Edit as kindly suggested by Colleen V]:

The "up" following "grew" can be omitted.  Or you might choose from: "expanded", "increased", and "ballooned", among many others.

Comment: It might be helpful to suggest a good alternative for "grew up".

Answer (score 1):

Either *eventually* or *ultimately* is correct. If the statement is preceded by the progressive steps leading to the crash, I'd use eventually. If the statement is by itself, or mostly unrelated to previous content, I'd use *ultimately*. If you're talking about the process of memory usage increasing, use *eventually*. If you mean only the outcome, use *ultimately*.

Delete the word, *up*.